# checkAll, uncheckAll not working properly post user interaction with an individual checkbox

Tags: css, angular

I have recently learnt angular from udemy. I was trying to use this a custom checkbox in my angular app. The problem is not with the checkbox itself but the ui not getting updated on checkAll, uncheckAll *after user interaction with an individual checkbox*

My implementation on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjh2wi)

Things i have tried:

- using timeout (i have used it to get autofocus working)
- using ChangeDetectorRef detectChanges()
- using template forms but tr/tbody won't render even if i wrap tbody in it
- using reactive forms (not very sure if i did it correctly)

Steps to reproduce:

1. click on any checkbox but the first one.
2. click on the first checkbox checkAll, uncheckAll... It doesn't work on the checkbox clicked in the first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `checked` attribute describes the **default** state of the field. **Removing it will have no effect if the field has been interacted with (or if its checked property has already been modified)**. `сhecked` property can be modified by user interaction(click on checkbox)

You should be manipulating `checked` **property** instead since it represents **the current state**.

```
checkAll() {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLInputElement>('input[type=checkbox]');
  inputs.forEach(input => input.checked = true)
}

uncheckAll() {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll<HTMLInputElement>('input[type=checkbox]');
  inputs.forEach(input => input.checked = false)
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-htdjfu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

> **Note:** this is not quite Angular way to work with form controls. You shouldn't be touching DOM directly in order to update control value